# Disble Auto-send Activation EMail

Tags: docusignapi

Is there any option in DocuSign to turn-off activation email, checked in both New Interface and Classic Interface. I am able to create the user using REST API v2 but don't want activation email to be sent as through API Call only I am setting the password also.

This is the Request Body:

```js
{
  "newUsers":[{ 
       "email":"'.$email.'", 
       "userName":"'.$username.'",
       "password":"'.$password.'",
       "forgottenPasswordInfo":{
           "forgottenPasswordAnswer1":"'.$secAnswer.'", 
           "forgottenPasswordQuestion1":"'.$secQuestion.'", 
        },
       "groupList": [{
          "groupId": "'.$groupId.'",
          "groupName": "'.$groupName.'",
          "permissionProfileId": "'.$permissionSet.'"
       }] 
   }]
}
```

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior depends on your account settings (account plan), please contact your Account Manager to change this.

Comment: I enquired with DocuSign Team [https://support.docusign.com/contactSupport]. They informed that this is a DocuSign default setting and can't be changed neither in demo account nor in live account. Currently I am working with developer sandbox account - demo account.